# BRL-CAD orot command doesn't seem to fail, but doesn't look rotated

Tags: 3d, tcl, cad

mged doesn't seem to complain with my syntax, but when I open the
graphic window the wireframe nor raytrace the motor doesn't look like
it was rotated relative to the cap. (this should look like a
spray-paint can cap with a small motor inside it)

```
title My Database1
units mm
in motor_28BYJ_48__main_body_cyl1.s rcc 0 0 0 0 0 19 14.0
in motor_28BYJ_48__wire_square1.s rpp -7.3 7.3 -17 0 0 19
c motor_28BYJ_48__main_body1.c motor_28BYJ_48__wire_square1.s u
motor_28BYJ_48__main_body_cyl1.s
in motor_28BYJ_48__mounting_wings_rect1.s rpp -17.5 17.5 -3.5 3.5 18 19
in motor_28BYJ_48__left_wing_hole1.s rcc -17.5 0 18 0 0 1 2.1
in motor_28BYJ_48__left_wing_curve1.s rcc -17.5 0 18 0 0 1 3.5
in motor_28BYJ_48__right_wing_hole1.s rcc 17.5 0 18 0 0 1 2.1
in motor_28BYJ_48__right_wing_curve1.s rcc 17.5 0 18 0 0 1 3.5
c motor_28BYJ_48__wings_chamfered1.c
motor_28BYJ_48__left_wing_curve1.s u
motor_28BYJ_48__right_wing_curve1.s u
motor_28BYJ_48__mounting_wings_rect1.s
c motor_28BYJ_48__wings_left_subtracted1.c
motor_28BYJ_48__wings_chamfered1.c - motor_28BYJ_48__left_wing_hole1.s
c motor_28BYJ_48__wings_block1.c
motor_28BYJ_48__wings_left_subtracted1.c -
motor_28BYJ_48__right_wing_hole1.s
in motor_28BYJ_48__body_to_shaft_base1.s rcc 0 8 19 0 0 1.5 4.5
in motor_28BYJ_48__shaft_base1.s rcc 0 8 20.5 0 0 2.5 2.5
in motor_28BYJ_48__shaft_key_cyl1.s rcc 0 8 23.0 0 0 6 2.5
in motor_28BYJ_48__shaft_key_rpp1.s rpp -2.5 2.5 6.5 9.5 23.0 29.0
c motor_28BYJ_48__shaft_key1.c motor_28BYJ_48__shaft_key_cyl1.s +
motor_28BYJ_48__shaft_key_rpp1.s
c motor_28BYJ_48__shaft1.c motor_28BYJ_48__body_to_shaft_base1.s u
motor_28BYJ_48__shaft_base1.s u motor_28BYJ_48__shaft_key1.c
r motor_28BYJ_48__COMPLETE1.g u motor_28BYJ_48__main_body1.c u
motor_28BYJ_48__wings_block1.c u motor_28BYJ_48__shaft1.c
Z
draw motor_28BYJ_48__COMPLETE1.g
oed motor_28BYJ_48__COMPLETE1.g
motor_28BYJ_48__main_body1.c/motor_28BYJ_48__main_body_cyl1.s
orot 90 90 90
Z
in aerosol_can_snap_cap__main_body_cyl1.s rcc 0 0 0 0 0 41.5 33.55
in aerosol_can_snap_cap__inner_main_body_cyl1.s rcc 0 0 0 0 0 39.5 31.55
r aerosol_can_snap_cap__cap_shell1.r u
aerosol_can_snap_cap__main_body_cyl1.s -
aerosol_can_snap_cap__inner_main_body_cyl1.s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I needed to add the `accept` command after `orot`!